# Implementing BROSH.io Marketing Automation: Need Guidance

Tags: automation, crm

I am currently working on implementing marketing automation for my project using [BROSH.io](https://www.brosh.io). I have heard great things about this tool and its ability to turn prospects into leads and paying customers. However, I am facing some challenges in the implementation process.

I appreciate any advice, tips, or resources you can provide to help me successfully implement BROSH.io marketing automation for my project. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

By the way, this is what I already did: I installed the app and Chrome extension. I tried it on LinkedIn, which worked okay, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly...